# Light Linking blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

I'm a Maya user and have just started down the Blender path but I've hit a road block when it comes to a light linking option?

If I just want to light one object with one light and leave everything else unaffected how do I achieve this?

I use this trick a lot in my animations so it would be much appreciated if anyone has an answer. Many thanks.

(I'm rendering with Eevee).

Comment: Blender doesn't have light exclusions or lighting groups features. Maybe you can achieve somethign equivalent with render layer exclusions, but I never tried myself

Comment: I haven't got into Evee yet, nor 2.8, but in earlier versions, Duarte Farrajota Ramos' suggestion will achieve this.  Place those objects to be affectd by this light in a layer of their own and add the light(s) to that layer.

In the light's property at right, tick "This Layer Only" box.  That will prevent the light from affecting other layers.  Keep in mind that lighting in other layers that aren't also ticked as exclusive will affect these objects.