# Configuring an object to ignore one light source

Tags: light, lighting, render-layers, layers

I would like to configure an object to ignore one particular light source (sun) in Cycles - to receive no light from the sun. Is this possible? I've looked online, but most posts I found were either 5+ years old, or were unanswered.

I have made a sample file with a cube and a sphere in two different collections. I would like the sun to cast light only on the sphere, not on the cube. 
[Sample](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AohDmDW98tXLkD5tnmyEhzGe8MRD?e=0f9NiI)

Comment: I see some answers that use Compositing, so I guess it still works in 2.8. Someone asked the same question in january: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129575/light-linking-blender-2-8

Comment: That is true, but the answer in that question suggests using layers, which are no longer present in 2.8 - for example, the answer says "In the light's property at right, tick This Layer Only box.", but there's no checkbox like that in 2.8 anymore. I know about the concept of collections, but despite moving objects to different collections, they're all still lit by the sun.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: Only one light source? Meaning other light should light the cube?

Comment: Yes, but the reason for my question is because I just need to selectively exclude an object from receiving light from a light source.

Comment: And the cube will cast shadow from the sun?

Comment: May or may not - not important, the key thing is whether it is receiving light or not.

Comment: Well so layers works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97161/discussion-between-ondrej-and-lemon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading through documentation, which is currently not entirely precise on this particular topic, I have found out and proved in practice that the way to solve my problem is indeed using two view layers. My scene now includes two collections - one contains the first set of objects and their light source, the other one includes the object that is not to be receiving light from the first collection's light sources. The view layers then control the visibility of each collection and its contents. This means that during render, each view layer/collection is rendered separately, and both rendered outputs are then combined together in compositing.

Comment: How is this achieved precisely please? If I recreate your experiment as you describe it: two collections, each with an object and a dedicated light source, and then render, both objects are lit by both lights. Is there some way you have set this up in compositing so that on render it restricts the collection lights to the objects in that collection?